# How to add time out using timer C#?

Tags: c#

I'm making a problem to received the data using Serial Port. LRx in my code is the data receive and timeout is the timer i set to wait for the response in 1MS. After 1Ms and still no response (LRX still equal 0) the cout will increase 1. After 3 times still no response and Error box will appear.

I have tried to make While loop to check condition of LRx and timeout but it look like i stuck in the While loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    if(!transfer)
                    {

                        for(int count = 0; count <3; count++)
                        {
                            ReadCoils((byte)(i + 1));
                            timeout = false;
                            timer2.Interval = 1;
                            timer2.Enabled = true;
                            while ((LRx == 0) && (!timeout)) { };

                            if (LRx != 0)
                            {
                                DataProcess();
                                count = 4;
                            }
                        }

                        if(transfer)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Slave " + (i+1) + " Not Responding", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome here.

Comment: Instead of `count = 4;` I guess you should have `break;`

Comment: Do you have limitations on using TPL and async/await?

Comment: Maybe no limitations im trying to find anyway to fix that problem